# Windows Security Real-time protection - Removing VBA

Tags: excel, vba, security, ms-word

Yesterday, 9 March 2021, Windows Security started preventing me from saving the VBA in my Normal.dotm and Personal.xlsb files.

When this occurs, the content of Normal.dotm and Personal.xlsb is destroyed by Windows Security. The affected file (e.g. a typical spreadsheet) could be saved; but, the concurrently running Personal.xlsb would not save. If I cancel the save, and restart the office application (e.g. Excel), the Personal.xlsb file would open; but all its code would have disappeared. The same behavior occurs using Word and Normal.dotm. The problem exists on all of my machines that include this code or earlier versions of it.

This is particularly insidious because backup copies of files containing the code are similarly destroyed without warning when used. These backups were functional when they were saved months ago. If I open those, the code is instantly removed and the file size shrinks from something significant (e.g. 2000KB) to something like 8KB.

I deleted the Personal.xlsb and Normal.dotm files and allowed O365 to recreate them by recording a trivial macro. I could then re-import the code using MZTools; but, could not save the repopulated Personal.xlsb or Normal.dotm files. O365 would return ". . . cannot complete the save due to a file permission error".

By trial and error, I narrowed the cause of the problem to one comment and a series of statements. If I eliminate the comment and the statements, the files can save normally. The 'offensive' comment explains a longish Print statement that is used to construct a .bat file used to uninstall (i.e. delete) the files used by my application from a folder on the user's hard drive.

The strange thing is that even the comment alone is enough to trigger protective action by Windows Security. The 'offensive' comment is:

'   forfiles /p "c:\temp\Folder A" /c "cmd /c del c:\temp\Folder B@file"

If I turn off Real-time protection, I can function normally; but, as soon as I turn it back on, the problem resumes.

Actions taken to mitigate the issue include; but, are not limited to:

- Ran the free version of Malwarebytes and did not find any infections.
- All settings in W10 Windows Security are on.
- W10 is fully updated.
- 32-bit O365 (Desktop) is fully updated.
- 64-bit Dell Laptop is fully updated.

I've noticed a lot of updates to Windows 10 during this period and I've made a concerted effort to assure W10 and O365 are fully updated on all of our machines. The problem persists.

I suspect that an overeager Windows Security is scanning for a pattern of text similar to "del c:" and then throwing everything away just "to be sure to be sure".

The purpose of my code is to create an UnInstall.bat file. This file uses the forfiles command to look at the list of files in a specified folder in a shared location and then deletes similarly named files in a specified subfolder of %APPDATA% on the user's hard drive. A separate Install.bat file takes care of the installation; but, the code creating that file has not caused an issue. Please note that the VBA procedures creating the UnInstall.bat and Install.bat files have NOT been exercised during this period. Neither have the UnInstall.bat and Install.bat files been executed in recent memory.

I'm new to distributing software and this is my attempt to do so with the tools and skills that I have. I have not experimented with allowing Windows Security to restore or allow the action anyway; but, that would be a major obstacle to providing a simple update feature to my application as it stands.

Any suggestions? Work around?

Comment: Your method is one commonly used by a VBA virus. Windows thinks you are writing a virus. I would tell you that anything you can do in a .bat you can do from VBA. So why make the bat file at all? If you give more details about what you are doing then we could help you get there without making the bat file.

Comment: My application is a suite of VBA functions that supplement Office Applications using the Ribbon and/or MS Forms as the user interface. 

My objective is to place files that support my "application" in a location on a LAN that can be used to update files in various subfolders of the user's %APPDDATA% location. Because I place the files on the User's computer within the %APPDATA% the .bat file was effective for that -- until it wasn't. 

I accept that there is likely a better way and that the .bat file approach won't work in this more paranoid world. I'm looking forward to any suggestions.

Comment: I would use `Workbook_Open()` event to check if it's installed. If not, pop a box asking the user if they would like to install. If they click "yes" then it copies itself in to the desired location. I would use the `FileSystemObject` to perform the copy.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fileexists-method

Comment: I guess my install routine must still work. After installing, the controlling code ends up in STARTUP or XLSTART from which I can use FileSystemObject to do the Updating. Can it do that if the code is running? The UnInstall.bat was the cause of this trouble. It was to be a simple thing that a user could click on to remove the stuff previously sprinkled in the %APPDATA% world. I'll need to experiment to see if the "applications" can uninstall themselves while running. Thanks for your help. I like your motto. I must have spent the greatest part of the last 6 months converting garbage to data.

Comment: You can't update the file you are standing on. The best way to do an update would be to rename the current file by doing a SaveAs. Then open the new version and run the install there, close self. Now you've passed contol to the new book which copies itself to the installed location and deletes the backup version that was made in the SaveAs. This way you can abort and you still have your backup file in place.

Comment: I like your idea very much. Me thinks I need to read up on patterns. That's funny! I was just explaining it to my wife that "it's like trying to throw out all your ladders. You can do if for all the ladders you have except the one you're standing on."  Thanks for the steer in a direction I can follow.

Answer (score -1):

What is the name of the virus detected by Windows Security?
You could add them into exception list of Windows Security.

Comment: Windows Secuity did not identify the virus. 

For some reason, my single question and subsequent responses seem to have gotten me banned. I'm trying to rectify this; but, being banned from asking a question or responding to one makes it difficult to contribute to provide positive contributions to outweigh those answers which were poorly received.

Answer (score -1):

Windows Security did not name the virus. It just disappeared the files (even if I only previewed the files in Explorer).

The lines in my code that I needed to eliminate included:

1. This COMMENT statement that does not do anything!!!
   '   forfiles /p "c:\temp\Folder A" /c "cmd /c del c:\temp
   and
2. This Print statement built by doing a replace on a string including paths to folders
   Print #iFileNum, Replace("forfiles /p """ & m_sFolderServerAddins & """ /c ""cmd /c del " & m_sFolderUserAddins & "@file""", m_sAppData, "%AppData%")

m_sFolderServerAddins defines a path to a shared folder (e.g. Dropbox or Onedrive)
m_sFolderUserAddins defines a path to a folder on the User's computer.
m_sAppData defines a path to a folder on the developer's computer and is replaced by the string "%APPDATA%" in the resultant .bat file.

I've not determined if the problem was with "forfiles", "cmd", "del", or something else. All I'm sure of is that these lines were the problem. If my VBA included them, the whole file containing the VBA would be disappeared. Yikes.

My work around included:

1. Turning off Windows Security > Virus and threat protection > Real-time Protection
2. Saving copies of the files with new extensions (e.g. ".xlsb" to ".xlsb.masked")
3. Editing the original files to eliminate the problematic lines.
4. Turning on Windows Security > Virus and threat protection > Real-time Protection